# The installed version of WinRM does not support transport(s) [u'']

Tags: ansible, winrm

I'm trying to configure a bunch of Windows machines through Ansible and installed pywinrm correctly but Ansible is throwing an error message.

Command:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/hosts playbooks/common.yml -vvv
```

Error Message:

```
ASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************
task path: /media/sf_C_DRIVE/OnlyOnMyPC/ansible.rhel75.master/playbooks/common.yml:1
Using module file /home/jim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/windows/setup.ps1
fatal: [10.96.1.11]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The installed version of WinRM does not support transport(s) [u'']"
}
Using module file /home/jim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/windows/setup.ps1
fatal: [10.96.1.12]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The installed version of WinRM does not support transport(s) [u'']"
}
```

List of packages installed by pip are as below:

```
pip list pywinrm
Package                        Version
------------------------------ ----------
adal                           1.2.0
ansible                        2.7.4
ansible-lint                   3.5.1
applicationinsights            0.11.7
argcomplete                    1.9.4
asn1crypto                     0.24.0
azure-cli-core                 2.0.35
azure-cli-nspkg                3.0.2
azure-common                   1.1.11
azure-graphrbac                0.40.0
azure-keyvault                 1.0.0a1
azure-mgmt-batch               4.1.0
azure-mgmt-compute             2.1.0
azure-mgmt-containerinstance   0.4.0
azure-mgmt-containerregistry   2.0.0
azure-mgmt-containerservice    3.0.1
azure-mgmt-dns                 1.2.0
azure-mgmt-keyvault            0.40.0
azure-mgmt-marketplaceordering 0.1.0
azure-mgmt-monitor             0.5.2
azure-mgmt-network             1.7.1
azure-mgmt-nspkg               2.0.0
azure-mgmt-rdbms               1.2.0
azure-mgmt-resource            1.2.2
azure-mgmt-sql                 0.7.1
azure-mgmt-storage             1.5.0
azure-mgmt-trafficmanager      0.50.0
azure-mgmt-web                 0.32.0
azure-nspkg                    2.0.0
azure-storage                  0.35.1
backports.ssl-match-hostname   3.5.0.1
bcrypt                         3.1.4
certifi                        2018.11.29
cffi                           1.11.5
chardet                        3.0.4
colorama                       0.4.1
configobj                      4.7.2
configparser                   3.5.0
cryptography                   2.4.2
decorator                      3.4.0
entrypoints                    0.2.3
enum34                         1.1.6
humanfriendly                  4.17
idna                           2.7
iniparse                       0.4
ipaddress                      1.0.16
isodate                        0.6.0
javapackages                   1.0.0
Jinja2                         2.10
jmespath                       0.9.3
keyring                        17.0.0
knack                          0.3.3
lxml                           3.2.1
MarkupSafe                     1.1.0
monotonic                      1.5
msrest                         0.4.29
msrestazure                    0.4.31
oauthlib                       2.1.0
packaging                      18.0
paramiko                       2.4.2
perf                           0.1
pip                            18.1
pyasn1                         0.4.4
pycparser                      2.19
pycurl                         7.19.0
Pygments                       2.3.0
pygobject                      3.22.0
pygpgme                        0.3
PyJWT                          1.7.0
pyliblzma                      0.5.3
PyNaCl                         1.3.0
pyOpenSSL                      18.0.0
pyparsing                      2.3.0
python-dateutil                2.7.5
python-linux-procfs            0.4.9
pyudev                         0.15
pywinrm                        0.3.0
pyxattr                        0.5.1
PyYAML                         3.13
requests                       2.20.1
requests-oauthlib              1.0.0
schedutils                     0.4
SecretStorage                  2.3.1
setuptools                     0.9.8
six                            1.11.0
slip                           0.4.0
slip.dbus                      0.4.0
tabulate                       0.8.2
typing                         3.6.6
urlgrabber                     3.10
urllib3                        1.24.1
wheel                          0.30.0
xmltodict                      0.11.0
yum-metadata-parser            1.1.4
```

No idea what is the problem and how to resolve it.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear you are not setting [`ansible_winrm_transport:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/windows_winrm.html#authentication-options) or, worse, you have set it to the empty string.

Comment: Thank you, my bad, it got deleted while editing and I didn't realized that. Fixed now and it works well.